# Export blender animation to three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, blender

i'm trying to convert a blender animation to a .json file, with the three.js addon for blender. i'm not a pro in blender, so please explain it for dummies.
everytime i click on 'export->Three.js(.json)', i get a error message from blender.

[blender error message http://s23.postimg.org/gu5mv8u7u/error_screenshot_blender.jpg](http://s23.postimg.org/gu5mv8u7u/error_screenshot_blender.jpg)

i have no idea where the error is. how can i solve this problem?
for a better understanding i uploaded the blender file too.
http://www.filedropper.com/walking_1

many thanks in advance.

Comment: your error message failed to load

Comment: also; I am having lots of issues with getting animations to export in the latest exporter. Some people have chosen to still use the old r69 version

Comment: oh thank you so much! :D i try it now since 3 days, and nothing helped. it exports a json file, i will try it later in my code if everthing is fine. you are my hero of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial, it helps me in basic blender

https://devmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/creating-skeletal-animation-in-blender-and-exporting-it-to-three-js/

Comment: thank you. i know this tutorial, but i will try it again.
thanks to repsac, i have now the .json file. :)

Comment: @Martin - This tutorial has been removed. This is an example of why it's important to post content of pointed sources into a response. Do you have any information on the content?